# Mark JavaScript as Safe

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to run a javascript that installs a utility on a client's system via web browser.  I appear to have put something together that does the trick but in doing so I need to change IE's browser's settings to enable "Initilize and script ActiveX controls not marked safe for scripting". This obviously cannot work in the real world. If this setting is not enabled all that is displayed on the web browser is a discreet "Error on Page" on the bottom of the web browser. I would ultimately like to have the script marked as safe so the clients would be prompted to run the ActiveX control.  So my question is how do I mark a javascript as safe. I also like to point out that our web pages are created using .NET's razor's engine (MVC3) so a compatible solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
cshtml snippet

script language=JavaScript

function launchExecutable(executableFullPath)

{

 var shellActiveXObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

 shellActiveXObject.Run(executableFullPath, 1, false);

 shellActiveXObject = null;

}

script
....
```

Comment: If that was possible, it would make all those browser specific security settings totally pointless...

Comment: Even if you could get the ActiveX control run (with certificated digital signature?), there will be some issues. `Run` only opens (a new tab in) the user's default browser. If the "executableFullPath" is something like "http-protocol//executableFullPath.exe", it won't pass browser anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You'll never be able to get that ActiveX control marked safe, because it gives the website *carte blanche* to do whatever it wants with full user privileges.

No website I've ever seen installs applications the way you're talking about. They either have a browser plugin for each browser they expect their client to use that is first installed into the browser that then downloads and installs the application (which I personally loathe, Adobe), or they simply give you a link/redirect to a `.exe` or `.msi` or `.deb` or whatever installer that requires the user to click a dialog box to start the download and install.

The Javascript for the latter is a simple redirect (if needed at all), and the work is all on the webserver making sure it has the proper MIME type of the file you're providing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't that your Javascript is unsafe, it's that the ActiveX control you're using isn't marked as being safe for scripting. The only way around this is to use an ActiveX control that is marked as safe, but then you need to have the clients install that control.

I would probably take the approach of detecting the error (use `try/catch`), and display a message telling the user how to turn that option on.

Comment: I appreciate all your answers.  I knew I was asking a hairy question.  These are business requirements and we all know how the business folk like to dream.  How would I go about marking an ActiveX control as safe.  I'm still a noob to the front end so I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @user1013651 AFAIK you can't, unless you're the developer of the ActiveX control. You would need to change code to mark it as safe, and then the recompiled control would still need to be installed on all client machines. I think really you should look into a different way of doing this... these security settings exist for a reason, and for this particular control, it's to protect users from random websites running arbitrary shell commands.

Comment: @user1013651 As alternatives: 1. You could provide the application as a standard installer; 2. If you are developing the application you're trying to install, you could make it a Click-Once application that installs from the browser; 3. Develop your own ActiveX control to install the application, this will make it easier on the users since they will get the standard IE message that you need to install a component.

Comment: I am developing the installer. We do have a Click-Once install that we are currently installing from web browsers, but it requires end-users to "keys" so to speak. We would like to eliminate this user input since it is error prone so we would like to run an install that we would pass parameters too. It appears I would have to create an ActiveX control that implements IObjectSafety in order to mark the control as safe. Is this the right course of action?